# Getting all values based on value in another table

Tags: mysql, join

This should be really easy but for some reason me and my brain don't want to cooperate today.

I've got a table `sales` that contains a `brick_region` column. A brick region always belongs to a `region`. Now I want to select all values in `sales` that belong to the region of the specific brick region that I've selected. How do I do this?

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
JOIN brick_regions
ON (brick_regions.id = sales.brick_region)
WHERE sales.date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-30'
AND sales.brick_region = 2
```

But I want the last line to be this instead:

```
AND brick_regions.region = [region ID of the brick region with ID 2]
```

Comment: _my brain don't want to cooperate today_ Good one

Comment: Can't you just add `AND brick_regions.region=sales.brick_region`?

Comment: @Arion And how will the query then select those rows that don't necessarily belong to brick region 2?

Comment: Why all the upvotes for such a trivial question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try with a sub query?

```
SELECT * FROM sales 
LEFT JOIN brick_regions ON brick_regions.id = sales.brick_region 
WHERE sales.date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-30' 
AND brick_regions.region = (SELECT region FROM brick_regions WHERE id = 2);
```

Comment: @silkfire Oh ok, I changed my answer. Is it better that way?

Answer (score 0):

the descriptions of the question is hard :)
so you want to get some rows from sales, based on date, then 
get all records from sales that have the same brick_region of the selected rows (by date)?

if yes, how about this?

```
select * from sales where sales.brick_region IN(
select brick_region from sales WHERE 
WHERE sales.date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-30'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

> A brick region always belongs to a region table

Assume that you have `region` table. So this query may be

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
JOIN brick_regions
ON (brick_regions.id = sales.brick_region)
JOIN region
ON (brick_regions.region = region.id)
WHERE sales.date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-30'
AND brick_regions.region = 2
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
JOIN brick_regions
ON (brick_regions.id = sales.brick_region)
JOIN region
ON (brick_regions.region = region.id)
WHERE sales.date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-30'
AND region.id = 2
```